# How to get Publish location in code when using ClickOnce?

Tags: c#, wpf, deployment, clickonce

I have  a WPF ClickOnce deployed application.  Is there any way to get what directory was specified in the Publish configuration?  ie. I specified C:\MyLocation as the Publishing Folder Location.  Is it possible to retrieve this directory path via code in the application itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
if (System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed)
{
     var deploy = System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment;
     var uri = deploy.ActivationUri;
     // Also:
     //deploy.DataDirectory
     //deploy.UpdateLocation
}
```

For more documentation:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.deployment.application.applicationdeployment(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.deployment.application.applicationdeployment%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: thanks configFilePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetParent(deploy.UpdateLocation.LocalPath).Parent.FullName, StringConstants.ConfigFileName); worked for what i was trying to get

Comment: The code sample requires a reference to System.Deployment.dll. In my scenario (deploy via UNC path / file share) ActivationUri is null, but UpdateLocation returns the path to the deployed .application file.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else finds this later, like I did, this worked better for me:

```
Dim installExePath As String = System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.UpdateLocation.LocalPath
installExePath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(installExePath) & "\setup.exe"
'MsgBox("About to start " & installExePath)
Process.Start(installExePath)
Application.Exit()
```